# VPN Split Tunneling

Tags: vpn, lan, split-tunnel

I have a Windows computer connected to a local LAN and a remote LAN with two routers 192.168.10.1 and 192.168.20.1 and a target computer 192.168.10.10

After connecting to a VPN, windows connect to internet through VPN, the computer receives a remote LAN IP 192.168.20.10 and I can see the target 192.168.10.10.

If I uncheck the option "Use default gateway on remote network", I preserve the internet connection through the local LAN, but the target turns unreachable.

If I let it checked, the target is reachable, but the computer is connected to internet through the VPN.

How should I solve this to keep the internet traffic through the local LAN, and keep the remote DNS accesing only the remote LAN devices?

[This site](http://www.hostingjamaica.com/knowledgebase/10084/How-do-I-configure-VPN-split-tunnel-in-windows-7-and-windows-8.html) seems to solve the issue, but the images are not accesible

Comment: that one is a tough nut to crack. DNS server addresses are applied to interface configuration, so if the traffic to unknown hosts doesn't exit via that interface, your system won't resolve DNS names against your VPN target networks DNS servers. you could try putting host entries for systems on the other side of your VPN in your host file, or try implementing a DNS zone on your network to resolve queries for VPN'd hosts, but otherwise, if you change the default gateway, you won't be able to perform DNS lookups on the network beyond the VPN.

Comment: Are you using an IPSec or SSL VPN [OpenVPN]? If the latter, @user1686's answer can be added to the server or client config via OpenVPN's (respectively) `push route` or `route` options ([man page](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `route` command to add a route for 192.168.10.10/32 or 192.168.10.0/24 via your VPN interface.

```
route print        (to find out the interface number)

route add -p 192.168.10.0/24 if <interface#>
```

DNS has completely nothing to do with the issue you've described. If you're accessing a host by its IP address, then DNS doesn't even come into play at any time – its job is to resolve domain names *to* IP addresses, it doesn't decide which way to send the actual packets afterwards.

> This site seems to solve the issue, but the images are not accesible

All necessary information, including the commands to use, is provided as text in the article itself. The images only show an example of the commands being used.

Comment: If using OpenVPN, this can also be specified directly in the server or client config via the `push route` [server] or `route` [client] options